# Looking for tex to html converter

Tags: linux, conversion, html, latex

I need to convert a very large latex project (made up of many .tex and style files) into .html (or something similarly *non*-.pdf).

Can someone recommend a quality converter program?

Preferably, one that is:

- available on linux (specifically Ubuntu)
- actively maintained

If need be, I can accept converting tex or pdf to X to html too.

The following programs have failed to convert [nicely]:

- `latex2html`
- `tth`
- `pdf2html`

For example, the `latex2html` results are unreadable:

- Translating results in hundreds of errors of the type

> Error while converting image
>
> Error: Cannot read 'img69.png': No such file or directory
>   Converting image #69
>   pstoimg: Error: Cannot find file "/tmp/l2h11170/image069.ps": No such file or directory

- The resulting html has no formatting (it doesn't seem to have respected styles from the `TEXINPUTS` env variable)
- All the crossreferences, images or diagrams result in broken links (not surprising, given the errors).
- It looks like headers have been replaced by TOC references (e.g. 13#13 instead of the proper wording)

I'm probably reaching here - hoping for a magic conversion.  The document I have is hundreds of pages, and quite complicated.  I don't know tex, but I would imagine this document is relatively standard compliant.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you consider .dvi to be "non-.pdf"? :P

Comment: @Ignacio: hah... yes... but not exactly what I'm after :)

Comment: "nicely" is undefined.  So what problems are happening with latex2html?  Positioning problems?

Comment: @Peon : Thanks, sorry I didn't see that comment until now.  Updated the question with some of the problems I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [short list](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/latex.html#convert) of LaTeX to HTML converters. One of the ones listed is [`tth`](http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/) which is in the Ubuntu repositories ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/tth.1.html)).

Comment: +1, Thanks for the link, unfortunately those programs couldn't handle this document.